# VarChar can be composed of?

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes

Can a varchar datatype consist numeric values and special characters in it?
If yes, please elaborate.

Comment: This ***looks*** an assignment dump. If it is, please heed [How do I ask (and answer) homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). Else: [What *are* you trying to achieve?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing much I'd like to *elaborate*. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1822) (11g version; pick any other you might be using) explains mostly everything:

> The VARCHAR2 datatype stores variable-length character strings.

Example:

```
SQL> create table test (col varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> -- string
SQL> insert into test values ('abc');

1 row created.

SQL> -- number - implicitly converted to varchar2 datatype
SQL> insert into test values (100);

1 row created.

SQL> -- special characters - not exactly "special", as they are enclosed into
SQL> -- single quotes so they are actually treated as "strings", but yes - you
SQL> -- can store them into a varchar2 column as well
SQL> insert into test values ('#$%');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

COL
--------------------
abc
100
#$%

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an indeterminate length string data type. It can hold numbers, letters and special characters.For varchar you need to check ASCII and EXTENDED ASCII character as these are allowed in a char/varchar field.

[image]